# tool to record windows action?

Tags: windows, macros

My boss give me a job to record some hundreds script manually, it would break my fingers...is there any free tool for recording and playback windows' mouse and keyboard action??

I am on win xp. The tool need to be safe, I don't want any virus/trojan/mali hidden in the software.

Comment: I wrote one ages ago to use in testing software. Last time I tried it, it still worked, on XP. It just captures window event messages, writes them to a file, and then another app plays them back. I'm always a little nervous about tools like that, wondering if it could be used by the wrong people to collect passwords or whatever.

Comment: http://camstudio.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mainly use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) but I have also used [MortScript](http://www.sto-helit.de/index.php?module=page&entry=ms_overview&action=view&menu=29) before.

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is nearly completely backward compatible with AutoIt v2, and it has a macro recorder whereas [MortScript](http://www.sto-helit.de/index.php?module=page&entry=ms_overview&action=view&menu=29) has no recording feature.

Comment: great! I have to modify to script after the recording because it is not working, but finally it is working!

Comment: Does Autoit have a macro recorder?